# Calculating (the orbits under the action of) the group generated by two 1-parameter subgroups acting on a Euclidean space: is there a method?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, lie-groups

I have a 5-dimensional Euclidean space, $E$, with an orthonormal basis ${\bf x}, {\bf y}_{1}, {\bf w}_{1}, {\bf y}_{2}, {\bf w}_{2}$ and two transformations:
$$
A_{1} : -{\bf x} + {\bf y}_{1} \mapsto {\bf w}_{1}, \quad {\bf w}_{1} \mapsto {\bf x} - {\bf y}_{1}, \quad 
{\bf y}_{2} \mapsto {\bf 0}, \quad {\bf w}_{2} \mapsto {\bf 0} 
$$
and
$$
A_{2} : -{\bf x} + {\bf y}_{2} \mapsto {\bf w}_{2}, \quad {\bf w}_{2} \mapsto {\bf x} - {\bf y}_{2}, \quad 
{\bf y}_{1} \mapsto {\bf 0},\quad {\bf w}_{1} \mapsto {\bf 0}.
$$
I am trying to calculate the orbit of a generic point in $E$ under the action of the group, $G_{A_{1}, A_{2}}$, generated by the 1-parameter groups $t \mapsto e^{t A_{1}}, t \mapsto e^{t A_{2}}$.

Here are approaches I have tried and challenges encountered (which are almost surely from my lack of familiarity with the needed theory, so an answer like "read X" is a great answer).

1. Calculate the Lie algebra generated by $A_{1}, A_{2}$ with the Lie bracket defined as the commutation: $[A_{1}, A_{2}] = A_{2} A_{1} - A_{1} A_{2}$.  I am getting that the dimension is no lower than 6.  But even having a basis for the Lie algebra, is there a theory for determining the group $G_{A_{1}, A_{2}}$?  (The underlying field is the reals, not algebraically closed, so Dynkin diagrams would not apply.)
2. Trying to consider, first, the two 1-parameter groups as if acting on two disjoint 3-D Euclidean spaces (then the orbit of a point is the torus $S^{1} \times S^{1}$), and then trying to calculate the topological factor space $(S^{1} \times S^{1}) / \sim$ by a suitable relation $\sim$ (which identifies two 1-dimensional subspaces from each 3-D space), but have had a hard time "seeing" the factor space.

Anyway, if there is a theory, I'd appreciate some sources.  If I am missing something straightforward, being pointed toward it would be great.

Comment: Could this be related to the Banach-Tarski paradox?

Comment: @Chrystomath I don't see how, but perhaps it could.

Comment: Since you mentiion $\mathbb S^1$, do you mean $e^{tS_i}$ instead of $e^{tA_i}$, where $S_i$ are elements so that $e^{S_i} = A_i$?

Comment: @ArcticChar, My thinking is $A_{i} = \left.{d \over dt}\right|_{t=0} e^{t A_{i}}$, I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: Since you mentioned $\mathbb S^1$, I suppose you think that $e^{tA_i}$ are rotations. But it is not. (e.g. Take the rotation $A$ of $x-y$ plane by $\pi/2$ in $\mathbb R^3$. Then $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 & 0  \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and thus $e^{tA} = \begin{pmatrix}\cos t & -\sin t & 0 \\\sin t& \cos t & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & e^t\end{pmatrix}$ is not a rotation.

Comment: @ArcticChar, I see.  Thank you for catching this: it is a mistake in my formulation.  I'll edit the question details.